# Hybris Beanshell script start the business process

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, beanshell

I want to create Beanshell script to start the business process for single order.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does my answer reply to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your beanshell should be something like this :

```
BusinessProcessService processService =
    (BusinessProcessService) Registry.getApplicationContext()
    .getBean("businessProcessService");
OrderProcessModel businessProcessModel =
    processService.createProcess(PROCESS_CODE, PROCESS_NAME);
processService.startProcess(businessProcessModel);
```

Make sure to put a proper PROCESS_CODE, a proper PROCESS_NAME and set any useful property for businessProcessModel.